# What is the difference between the campaign-development tag and the world-building tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am unable to articulate the difference between these tags. Looking at the questions did not help. Should they be merged or setup as synonyms? If so, which one should we keep?

[Questions tagged campaign-development](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campaign-development)
[Questions tagged world-building](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building)

Answer (score 4):

I think there's room for both.  World building is all the usual "making the geography" thing.  Developing a campaign has more to do with the specific plotline etc at hand - the "adventure."  Now having said that some of the things tagged CD should have been tagged WB...

Answer (score 3):

World building is probably somewhat larger in scope, in theory: you could develop a campaign within an existing world. In practice I don't think there's a ton of difference. I would say campaign-development is the right parent tag; it focuses on the activity of roleplaying rather than being a term that's used as often in writing fiction. Me am purist. Grunt.

Edit: as per mxy's comment, I don't think there's a need for quick action here -- there could be a difference, and if one develops or is encouraged that'd be nice.

Comment: I agree. World building is a fictional activity. Campaign development is what we do for rpgs. Though I could see questions with both that are specific about developing world stuff that fits for rpgs or is derived from assumptions that only make sense for rpgs.

Comment: There are campaign-development activities that have nothing to do with world-building, but all world-building (in the R-pG context) necessarily contributes to the development of at least one (possibly hypothetical) campaign. I agree that campaign-development is the parent.

Comment: I'd disagree: I'd say they're independent, or at best `world-building` is the parent. One world can house many campaigns (Faerûn!), and though one campaign rarely houses many worlds, when you're talking sci-fi or multi-dimensional games one campaign will involve a *lot* of world-building.

Answer (score 3):

For me, campaign development often suggests a smaller-scoped activity of adapting an existing setting for a specific group of players.

World building, on the other hand, suggests creating a setting that can be used for many "campaigns."

Specifically talking about D&D games, campaign development often entails using the default setting or a boxed setting (Points of Light, Forgotten Realms, Planescape, etc.). World building always means creating a new setting.

I think they're very different activities and would like to see the tags kept separate.